# Single.concat report error and continue to the next

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm trying to use RxJava with Android to asynchronously update my view. When user clicks the movie from the list in the RecyclerView, I want to present him first with the movie from the database, if present. Then I want to fetch the latest information and update the database as well as UI. I'm trying to use `concat` method and its variant but it does not work.

I have skipped other codes only to post the relevant RxJava methods that are fetching data as the rest is working fine.

When I disable network connection with the code below (hence remote returns error), the code below does not display data from the database at all. Only it reports the error. Which means the local is not resolving.

```
    public Flowable<Movie> getMovie(final int id) {
        return Single.concat(mLocal.getMovie(id), mRemote.getMovie(id).doOnSuccess(data -> {
            mLocal.save(data);
        })).onErrorResumeNext(error->{
            return Flowable.error(error);
        });
    }
```

And in this code, it works fine, except now that I don't get the error message (and rightly so, since I have replaced it with new stream from the database)

```
    public Flowable<Movie> getMovie(final int id) {
        return Single.concat(mLocal.getMovie(id), mRemote.getMovie(id).doOnSuccess(data -> {
            mLocal.save(data);
        })).onErrorResumeNext(error->{
            return mLocal.getMovie(id).toFlowable();
        });
    }
```

Now, how can I get database data first and then fire network call next to update data and get errors from the database or network call?

**UPDATE**

The latest method code

```
    // calling getMovie on mLocal or mRemote returns Single
    public Flowable<Movie> getMovie(final int id) {
        return Single.concat(mLocal.getMovie(id), mRemote.getMovie(id).doOnSuccess(data -> {
            mLocal.insertMovie(data);
        })).onErrorResumeNext(error -> {
            return Flowable.error(error);
        });
    }
```

Here is how I call them

```
    public void loadMovie(int id)
    {
        Disposable d = mRepo.getMovie(id)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread(), true)
                .doOnSubscribe(subscription -> {
                    subscription.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
                    //post progress here
                })
                .subscribe(data -> {
                            //onNext 
                        },
                        error -> { 
                           //onError
                        },
                        () -> {
                            //onComplete
                        }
                );

        mDisposables.add(d);
    }
```

Comment: The original should have worked, unless you have something like `getMovie().observeOn()`. Errors cut ahead in `observeOn` and you should use [this overload](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#observeOn-io.reactivex.Scheduler-boolean-) to avoid that.

Comment: I have updated with the code of how I call it. I have even tried the overload I don't get a local data when there is a network error

Comment: You can apply `doOnSuccess` to the `mLocal.getMovie()` to see if it actually has data. You could then try without concatenating to see if there is a dataloss elsewhere along the flow.

Comment: let me try that!

Comment: Checked under debugger it indeed have the data. Just returning `mLocal.getMovie(id).toFlowable()` works fine and data gets there. I just not have an idea what is happening.

Comment: After tracing further, I have found an error. The app uses MVVM and so when data is ready, I post it to LiveData with `postValue` method. The RxJava part works fine. Only that livedata part doesn't work. Thank you for confirmation and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With affirmation that my code works and guides on troubleshooting from [@akarnokd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61158/akarnokd) I found the latest code (see OP) works flawlessly. The result of RxJava chain is posted to LiveData object which should update View. Unfortunately it only posts the latest data (which is an error) and skips the first (which is the data from the database).

I will deal with that but since the post deals with RxJava, I will consider this solved!